# Field/datatype for searchable address components?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, django, address

I'm using Django with Postgres, and I'm looking for a field/datatype to store address components that come from Google Places API in this format:

```
"address_components": [
  {"long_name": "27", "short_name": "27", "types": ["street_number"]},
  {"long_name": "Dromore Crescent", "short_name": "Dromore Crescent", "types": ["route"]},
  {"long_name": "Westdale South", "short_name": "Westdale South", "types": ["neighborhood", "political"]},
  {"long_name": "Hamilton", "short_name": "Hamilton", "types": ["locality", "political"]},
  {"long_name": "Hamilton Division", "short_name": "Hamilton Division", "types": ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]},
  {"long_name": "Ontario", "short_name": "ON", "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]},
  {"long_name": "Canada", "short_name": "CA", "types": ["country", "political"]},
  {"long_name": "L8S 4A8", "short_name": "L8S 4A8", "types": ["postal_code"]}
],
"formatted_address": "27 Dromore Crescent, Hamilton, ON L8S 4A8, Canada",
"place_id": "ChIJtZiMplGbLIgRcGQ4Anc337s",
```

The goal is to allow users to see this row in their results if they search for `westdale`, `L8S 4A8`, `l8s4a8`, `27 dromore`, `hamilton`, etc.

How should this data be saved?

1. Save it as-is in `jsonb`? There's a lot of duplicate text, for instance `'long_name'` and `'short_name'` keep appearing over and over, wasting space.
2. Strip all the keys and only keep the actual meat of the components in a `varchar[]`, ex. `['27', 'Dromore Crescent', 'Westdale South', 'Hamilton', 'Hamilton Division', 'Ontario', 'Canada', 'L8S 4A8']`?
3. Normalize this data in layers of foreign-key related tables? Four tables are required to normalize this: `address_to_component`, `component`, `component_type`, `component_to_component_type`. (I actually started with this, but couldn't wrap my head around how to go about querying it.)
4. Something else?

Comment: How many of those attributes will realistically have a different `short_name` and `long_name`? I can see `country` and `administrative_area_level_` do.

Comment: I'm not too concerned about the `short_name`, I think it'd be practical to ignore it if that makes it a lot easier.

Comment: @DavidTan is the answer provided here satisfactory, if so please choose it or ask more questions.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I ended up deciding to do something else (I can paste the Django code here if anyone is interested). Reading your answer again, it was very informative and I think would be helpful for future readers so I'll mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*UPDATE: see [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/165915/2639) for a working example of the below*

How would I store it? What you've got is

- User data (formatted_address)
- Normalized address breakdown (address_components)

I would store only the `formatted_address` or whatever the user provided. Why?

- I don't trust Django or whatever you're integrating with
- I want the ability to re-normalize addresses when new data comes out.

PostGIS is a PostgreSQL extension that provides `address_standardizer`. You can install `standardize_address` like this,

```
CREATE EXTENSION address_standardizer;
CREATE EXTENSION address_standardizer_data_us;
```

From there you can provide the formatted address to [`standardize_address`](http://postgis.net/docs/standardize_address.html)

```
SELECT standardize_address( formatted_address )
```

This will return a composite type [stdaddr](http://postgis.net/docs/stdaddr.html). I may cache this against the version of the extension and the timestamp of the call to `standardize_address`.

The `stdaddr` composite type will also be much easier to geocode which you always seem to need at some point if you're going down this path.

All of that said, [Django appears to be using Google Maps to normalize their addresses](https://github.com/furious-luke/django-address). If that works for you, you can run with it. I'm sure that's not a bad source of address normalization. How you store that, will depend entirely on how *you* want to query it. If you're even querying it at all and not just presenting a profile. If you're not `JOIN`ing based on any of that I think a new column `django_google_maps jsonb` is a great starting point.

Comment: `stdaddr` and `address_standardizer_data_us` both look to be USA specific; do you know if they are available internationally?

Comment: @DavidTan if you're looking for internationalized address standardization across countries, ask another question. =)