# How do I parse addresses in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, address

Let's say for instance that I want to parse these addresses for the Chicken Ranch

```
Chicken Ranch
10511 Homestead Rd
Pahrump, NV 89061

Chicken Ranch
1600 Pennsylvania Avenue
NW Washington, D.C. 20500
```

In both of these cases, I'd like to get rid of `Rd` and `Avenue`. For instance in the first case, I'd like to get "Homestead", and in the second "Pennsylvania". Not every address has a designation like this though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a question address canonicalization and parsing. Essentially what you're talking about is handled through a [gazetteer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gazetteer) (geographical rule set). There are two ways to do this right,

1. [`address_standardizer`](http://postgis.net/docs/Address_Standardizer.html) from the PostGIS project and certainly better if you're only using United States addresses.
2. [`pgsql-postal`](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-postal) may be a better method for international addresses.

I'll show the address standardizer version for the address,

```
Chicken Ranch
10511 Homestead Rd
Pahrump, NV 89061
```

Using `standardize_address` from `address_standardizer`, returns a composite type of [`stdaddr`](http://postgis.net/docs/stdaddr.html). First we install it,

```
CREATE EXTENSION address_standardizer;
CREATE EXTENSION address_standardizer_data_us;
```

And, then we can use it like this.

```
SELECT * FROM standardize_address('us_lex',
   'us_gaz', 'us_rules', '10511 Homestead Rd, Pahrump, NV 89061');
 building | house_num | predir | qual | pretype |   name    | suftype | sufdir | ruralroute | extra |  city   | state  | country | postcode | box | unit 
----------+-----------+--------+------+---------+-----------+---------+--------+------------+-------+---------+--------+---------+----------+-----+------
          | 10511     |        |      |         | HOMESTEAD | ROAD    |        |            |       | PAHRUMP | NEVADA | USA     | 89061    |     | 
(1 row)
```

So you can see, `ROAD` is pulled out in `suftype`

Likewise,...

```
SELECT * FROM standardize_address('us_lex',
   'us_gaz', 'us_rules', '1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, NW Washington, D.C. 20500');
 building | house_num | predir | qual | pretype |     name     | suftype |  sufdir   | ruralroute | extra | city | state | country | postcode  | box |     unit     
----------+-----------+--------+------+---------+--------------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+------+-------+---------+-----------+-----+--------------
          | 1600      |        |      |         | PENNSYLVANIA | AVENUE  | NORTHWEST |            |       |      |       | USA     | D C 20500 |     | # WASHINGTON
```

Comment: How does one pass a table of values to the standardizer?  As in...SELECT * FROM standardize_address('us_lex',
   'us_gaz', 'us_rules', myTable.address_full);

Comment: @evan-carroll is there a way to get a standard abbreviation for `suftype`?

Comment: @cayblood USPS publishes a list, https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28apc_002.htm you'll have to link them up. Those kinds of questions btw are good for [opendata.se]