# How to Get the Second Sequence of Characters using Regular Expressions

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, regular-expression

I have a field with an address in it (ex. `68 TIDAL BREEZE DR`) and this regular expression gets everything before the last sequence (ex. `68 TIDAL BREEZE`):

```
substring (address from '(.*) ')
```

My question is, how do I modify this expression to get everything after the first sequence (ex. 68) and everything before the last sequence (ex. DR) like so: `TIDAL BREEZE`?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5.

Comment: The title (*'Second Word in an Attribute'*) asks for something else than the body of the question (*'everything after the first group (ex. 68) and everything before the last group'*). You might also define "group". Sequence of word characters? non-space characters? Separator is always a single space or something else? A couple more examples help if you should have a hard time to express the problem clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
postgres=# select substring('68 TIDAL BREEZE DR' from '\s+(.*)\s');
  substring
--------------
 TIDAL BREEZE
(1 row)
```

Lazy match the first whitespace character to chop the first bit off.

Comment: how would I use this same approach to get the prefix of an address ex. 'W' from 'W HOLLYWOOD BLVD'?

Comment: select substring('W HOLLYWOOD BLVD' from '(.+?)\s');

Comment: The regexp is pretty smart, I see no corner case or possible improvement. (For the question in the body of the Q.)

Answer (score -1):

## Not using a regex

I highly suggest you don't parse addresses with a regex. If you're looking for a better practice, there is a method of [parsing addresses demonstrated and explained in this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165915/how-do-i-parse-addresses-in-postgresql/165916#165916)

```
SELECT * FROM standardize_address(
  'us_lex','us_gaz','us_rules',
  '68 TIDAL BREEZE DR, Citytown Texas, 77346'
);
 building | house_num | predir | qual | pretype |     name     | suftype | sufdir | ruralroute | extra |   city   | state | country | postcode | box | unit 
----------+-----------+--------+------+---------+--------------+---------+--------+------------+-------+----------+-------+---------+----------+-----+------
          | 68        |        |      |         | TIDAL BREEZE | DRIVE   |        |            |       | CITYTOWN | TEXAS | USA     | 77346    |     | 
(1 row)
```

Or to get just certain values

```
SELECT house_num || ' Other Stuff ' || suftype AS whatever
FROM standardize_address('us_lex', 'us_gaz', 'us_rules',
  '68 TIDAL BREEZE DR, Citytown Texas, 77346'
);
       whatever       
----------------------
 68 Other Stuff DRIVE
(1 row)
```

Comment: how would I substitute '68 TIDAL BREEZE DR, Citytown Texas, 77346' with a column name that contained the following format for all addresses: '68 TIDAL BREEZE DR'?

Comment: @Matt I don't think you can parse just street addresses with it. You'd either have to give them a fictitious location (as I did), or this method wouldn't work. That said, if you've got it -- provide it. If not, this method may not work for you here.

Comment: I guess my question is, all of the examples I see using the standardize_address function are all using strings like '68 TIDAL BREEZE DR, Citytown Texas, 77346'. If I did add a new field to my table and concatenate it together with a bogus zip code and city name, how would I then use the column name in the 'from' statement instead of a string?

Comment: `SELECT a.* FROM georgetown.addresses CROSS JOIN LATERAL parse_address(address || ', Citytown Texas, 77346') AS a;`